# Runtime Exception in Android application: unable to inflate MapFragment

Tags: android

***i ' ve posted one question similar to this one, i' ve inserted the changes suggested to me***, but i  can't understand why is launching this exception yet.

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.testing.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.testing.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

mainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;

    private Button showBtn;
    private GoogleMap map = null;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location myLocation;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Display display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        showBtn.setClickable(false);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        display = new Display(map);

        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL).setSmallestDisplacement(10);

        if (locationClient != null)
            locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location listener called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        myLocation = location;
        if (myLocation != null)
            showBtn.setClickable(true);
        else
            showBtn.setClickable(false);

        display.clearMap();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 16));
        display.addMarker(newPosition, "My Title", "..and my comments go here");
        display.setCircleOnMap(newPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Locationclient Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.showBtn) {
            if (InternetStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)) {
                new ShowCloseUps(display, myLocation).execute();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection find one and retry!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (locationClient.isConnected() && locationClient != null) {
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            locationClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button 
          android:id="@+id/showBtn"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:text="@string/show"
          />

      <fragment 
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_above="@id/showBtn"
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
              map:cameraZoom="5"
              map:cameraTilt="30"
              map:uiCompass="false"
              map:uiRotateGestures="true"
              map:uiTiltGestures="true"
              map:uiZoomGestures="true"
              />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**my logcat tab UPDATED:**

```
    08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 1832
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at com.example.testing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     ... 11 more
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #25: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for null
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4759)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
08-11 08:46:40.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1832):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: as i know above logcat saying that the error is coming due to component accesing problem i mean Unable to start activity ComponentInfo means your declaring something else in xml and your accesing something else in java file or your trying to access component which is not present in xml if such knd of scene  is there this exception occurs as per my understanding this error is coming due to fragment may be am wrong but this is due to that fragment you may look around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line from your fragment

```
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

from `activity_main.xml` file.

Also remove this one:

```
map:cameraZoom="5"
map:cameraTilt="30"
map:uiCompass="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
```

Comment: @oIrC Because in your parent layout the XML schema is already added. So no need to add in any other child view. And if you add any other custom view or ad_banner then its schema will be added to your parent layout also rather than to it.

Comment: i' ve removed the line suggested, but this didn't fix the problem, and i' m getting `error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix near <fragment`

Comment: well, this fixed all, but why?

Comment: This is because that property accessible if you have added a that map schema to your parent layout but it has been removed that line. So that property is also not accessible so needed to remove.

Comment: i launched the emulator, but the app still force to quit, with the same exception. I made all your's suggestion on xml file, but i don't understand how to fix.

Comment: You are using Google Map V2 so i think it is better to test in real device rather than in emulator because map may be not launched in emulator and it takes much time. And if you want to launch map then your latest updated Google Play lib service installed in it.

Comment: i have the latest google play services installed,thanks for the advices.

Comment: Ok run it in real device and though will  get same error post log cat here

Comment: i have tested the app having the same result as the emulator, as you said i' ve poste the complete log cat.

Comment: you need to add this in your manifest file. <application>
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCyOMlgRyKqT9syQ-7aetOj0_VF1__Xkmg" />
 </application>                                                         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: i added the lines before updating log cat, see log cat updated.

Comment: for privacy i didn't insert my app key, but it is inserted into my manifest.

Comment: Because i have faced this type issue and problem was that. so

Answer (score 1):

Try to changes

```
<fragment 
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_above="@id/showBtn"
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
              map:cameraZoom="5"
              map:cameraTilt="30"
              map:uiCompass="false"
              map:uiRotateGestures="true"
              map:uiTiltGestures="true"
              map:uiZoomGestures="true"
              />
```

to

```
<fragment 

              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_above="@id/showBtn"
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
              map:cameraZoom="5"
              map:cameraTilt="30"
              map:uiCompass="false"
              map:uiRotateGestures="true"
              map:uiTiltGestures="true"
              map:uiZoomGestures="true"
              />
```

Hope this may help you